# Como saber que código no tiene registros en una tabla SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Estimados buenas tardes,

Estoy tratando de obtener un listado de códigos que están activos en una tabla (remples) pero que no generaron registro en otra tabla (rliquid).  Ocupaba el Not in luego de un select pero resulta ya que me muestra registros que si están en ambas tablas para ese periodo. .

motor SQL server 2012

```sql
SELECT 
  A.CODIGO
  , A.FECHA_ING
  , A.ESTADO

FROM REMPLESH A 

WHERE 

A.ESTADO IN ('A','P') 
AND A.CODIGO NOT IN(
    select CODIGO 
    from rliquid 
    where ames='202205' 
    and codigo=a.codigo
) 
AND A.FECHA_ING <=CONVERT(DATETIME,'31-05-2022',103)
 AND A.AMES='202205'
```

Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: ¿Que motor de base de datos estas usando? `MySQL`, `SQL Server`, `PostgreSQL`? Y si se puede ¿que versión?

Comment: esto: AND codigo = a.codigo no tiene sentido adentro del not in...

Comment: Gracias por responder.  SQL Server 2012

Comment: Pon un ejemplo de muestra para que se te pueda ayudar

Comment: ¿Puedes incluir datos de prueba y la estructura básica de las tablas?

Answer (score 0):

otra opción sería hacer un join

```
   SELECT 
          A.CODIGO
        , A.FECHA_ING
        , A.ESTADO
     FROM REMPLESH A 
LEFT JOIN rliquid B on b.ames=a.ames and b.codigo = a.codigo
    WHERE A.ESTADO IN ('A','P') 
      AND A.FECHA_ING <=CONVERT(DATETIME,'31-05-2022',103)
      AND A.AMES='202205'
      AND B.CODIGO is null
```

con el LEFT JOIN buscamos en la tabla "rliquid" los registros que existan en "remplesh" entonces, los que no existan en la tabla "rliquied" van a aparecer nulos.